# Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Jetpack Compose y me da un null pointer por el ViewModel

Tags: json, retrofit, jetpack-compose, viewmodel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del ViewModel es este:

```
    class HeroDeckViewModel:ViewModel(){
        private val _player = MutableLiveData<Player>()
    
        private val _nickNamePlayer = MutableLiveData<String>()
        val nickNamePlayer1: LiveData<String> = _nickNamePlayer
    
        private val _superHeroDeck  = MutableLiveData<List<SuperHero>>()
        val superHeroDeck:LiveData<List<SuperHero>> = _superHeroDeck
    
        init {
            getSuperHeroe()
        }
    
        fun onPlayer(nickName:String){
            _nickNamePlayer.value = nickName
        }
    
    
        fun getSuperHeroe(){
            //iniciamos una corrutina
            val superHeroesList = mutableListOf<SuperHero>()
            var superheroResponse: SuperHero? = null
            viewModelScope.launch {
                try {
                    repeat(2){
                        val numAleatorio = Random.nextInt(1, 732).toString()
                        val superHeroId = SuperHeroApi.retrofitService.getSuperHeroById(numAleatorio).trimIndent()
                        val gson = Gson()
                        superheroResponse = gson.fromJson(superHeroId, SuperHero::class.java)
                        superHeroesList.add(superheroResponse!!)
                    }
    
                }catch (e:IOException){
                    Log.e("getSuperHeroe", "Error al obtener superhéroes: ${e.message}")
                }
                _superHeroDeck.value = superHeroesList
            }
    
    
        }
        /**
         * calcula el poder de los personajes
         */
        private fun checkPuntos(){
            //calcula los puntos de cada superHero
            for(superHero in _superHeroDeck.value!!){
                val powerStats = superHero.powerStats
                val totalPowers = powerStats.power + powerStats.combat + powerStats.durability + powerStats.speed
                + powerStats.strength + powerStats.intelligence
    
                val powerPercentage = powerStats.power.toDouble() / totalPowers * 10
                val combatPercentage = powerStats.combat.toDouble() / totalPowers * 15
                val durabilityPercentage = powerStats.durability.toDouble() / totalPowers * 15
                val speedPercentage = powerStats.speed.toDouble() / totalPowers * 15
                val strengthPercentage = powerStats.strength.toDouble() / totalPowers * 20
                val intelligencePercentage = powerStats.intelligence.toDouble() / totalPowers * 25
            }
    
        }
    
    }
```

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación de cartas, el jugador puede tener un conjunto de cartas que se saca de una api de superHeroes cada una con su id, nombre, biografía y poderes. El jugador tendrá una lista de cartas con las que combatirá con otros jugadores. (Ahora mismo solo estoy haciendo la parte del jugador, es decir la local que consiste en que el jugador muestre varías cartas, en este caso he puesto 2)

Si alguien sabe que es lo que falla. El método importante es el de getSuperHeroe()
y aquí están las screens. Por cierto la lista en el método si que me mete los superHeroes que son guardados como objetos a partir del JSON

```
/*Contiene toda la pantalla*/
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun screen(heroDeckViewModel:HeroDeckViewModel){

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                ),
                title = {
                    Text("Hero-Deck")
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    text = "Bottom app bar",
                )
            }
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        ) {

            val heroDeck = heroDeckViewModel.superHeroDeck.value
            if(heroDeck==null){
                Text(text = "Cargando")
            }else{
                PhotosGridScreen(superheroes = heroDeck)
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * imprime la carta
 */
@Composable
fun SuperHeroCard(superHero:SuperHero){
    val urlImagen = superHero.image.url
    AsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(context = LocalContext.current)
            .data(urlImagen)
            .build(),
        contentDescription = "SuperHero",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
    
    Text(text = superHero.name)
    Text(text = superHero.powerStats.toString())
    
}


@Composable
fun PhotosGridScreen(superheroes: List<SuperHero>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(150.dp),
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(4.dp)
    ) {
        items(items = superheroes, key = { heroe -> heroe.id }) {
            heroe -> SuperHeroCard(superHero = heroe)
        }
    }
}
```